# Prevent auto scroll when prepend something

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, prepend

I have this code.

```
<div class="mes-all">
<div class="mes" id="1">test1</div>
</div>
<button id="add">Send</button>
```

And on every submit some `.mes` divs prepending to `.mes-all` div.But I want it not scroll auto,I want it maintain position same as before prepending divs above.

I have looked for solution in even this site,but couldn't find.
I can't control `height()` or `scrollTop()`, I don't know this functions very well,that's why I can't figure out the problem.
I have jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/83xq3b3L/

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
var $elem = $('#list');
var height = $elem.height();


$("#add").on("click",function(){
var id=parseInt($(".mes:first").attr("id"))+1;
$(".mes-all").prepend('<div class="mes"   id="'+id+'">test'+id+'</div>');
height+=30;
$(".mes-all").animate({scrollTop: height+"px"});

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "list" class="mes-all">
<div class="mes" id="1">test1</div>
</div>
<button id="add">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get the scrollHiehgt of the parent div and then scrollTop to that height.

So you code might look like this:

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var id = parseInt($(".mes:first").attr("id")) + 1;
  $(".mes-all").prepend('<div class="mes" id="' + id + '">test' + id + '</div>');
  var divHiehgt = $('.mes-all')[0].scrollHeight;

  $('.mes-all').scrollTop(divHiehgt);

});
```

```css
.mes-all {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.mes {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mes-all">
  <div class="mes" id="1">test1</div>
</div>
<button id="add">Send</button>
```

Or jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j8jaz10k/1/